# Javascript-new line display

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="upload"> 
    <input type="button"  onclick="uploadFile();" value="+">
    <script>
        function uploadFile() {
            var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
            x.setAttribute("type", "file");
            upload.appendChild(x);
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

After executing this code I am getting file upload button in same line. How to display the button line by line?

Answer (score 3):

Just add a linebreak, `<br>`, too:

```
function uploadFile() {
    var x = document.createElement("input");
    var br = document.createElement("br");
    x.setAttribute("type", "file");
    upload.appendChild(br); // (Make sure you add the `br` before the input)
    upload.appendChild(x);
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider [accepting this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), when the 15 minute cooldown expires.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to control this. One of them is to just add a line-break character `<br>`, which will result in your DOM looking like:

```
<div id="upload"> 
    <input type="button" onclick="uploadFile();" value="+">
    <br>
    <input type="file"/>
</div>
```

You would do this by doing:

```
<div id="upload"> 
  <input type="button" onclick="uploadFile();" value="+">
  <script>
    function uploadFile(){
      var br = document.createElement("br");
      var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
      x.setAttribute("type", "file");
      upload.appendChild(br);
      upload.appendChild(x);
    }
  </script>
</div>
```

A lot of positioning is done in styles though, and in such a case, nested  are common with floats to go left and right and what-not. Lets say you want to put that button anywhere, you can use the getElementById() method to get any other element that has an id in the dom, and append the button there.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp

```
<div id="upload"> 
  <input type="button" onclick="uploadFile();" value="+">
  <script>
    function uploadFile(){
      parent_node = document.getElementById('upload');
      var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
      parent_node.appendChild(x);
    }
  </script>
</div>
```

which would result in your DOM looking like:

```
<div id="upload"> 
  <input type="button" onclick="uploadFile();" value="+">
  <input type="file"/>
</div>
```

(probably exactly what you have now), point being, maybe CSS is how you want to position that input element.You can provide an id in javascript just like you did for type, with

```
x.setAttribute("id","some_unique_name")
```

Basically, a `<br>` will totally work to get it to a new line, but if you want to get fancy and use css to `display:block` / `float:right` and move things around a `<br>` might not provide the flexibility you are looking for. If not, give the element an `id` and look into some CSS!

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: Half your answer is about using css to position the element, but you're not giving an example of how that would work ;-)

Comment: haha true, i guess i only went so far. I explain how to add an id to an element, and a link to lessons about how to position elements based on id, thought maybe that would be enough.